# Slow query issue!

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql

Maybe someone can help me with this issue.
My site has a slow query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.*, g.title AS groupname, c.name AS category, v.name AS author, w.name as moderator, u.name AS editor 
FROM p38xt_k2_items as i 
LEFT JOIN p38xt_k2_categories AS c ON c.id = i.catid 
LEFT JOIN p38xt_viewlevels AS g ON g.id = i.access 
LEFT JOIN p38xt_users AS u ON u.id = i.checked_out 
LEFT JOIN p38xt_users AS v ON v.id = i.created_by 
LEFT JOIN p38xt_users AS w ON w.id = i.modified_by 
WHERE i.trash=0 ORDER BY i.id DESC LIMIT 0, 50;
```

I have checked every module that does k2 feeds, but was unable to find the 50 limit.
I also opened all .php of the /modules/* but even there I could not find: `SELECT DISTINCT i.*, g.title`

Does someone know were this query might be generated?!
Is there any Joomla Extension that can track the queries executed from the modules?!

**Solution:**
The issue of this problem was the K2 multicategory plugin that I was using on the site!

Comment: Please can you use the code format for your query so we can easily read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the **system debug** in Global Configuration/System.

Open a page using k2 and in the **Joomla! Debug Console** under **Database Queries** you will find every query executed on that page with execution time, used memory and a **Call Stack** that identifies every file involved.

---

You can also change allowed user groups and other options of **System - Debug plugin** under Extensions > Plugin to customize the debug console.

UPDATE: after some research the query was actually executed in backend area by latest k2 items module.

Comment: Hello,
Can I just enable the debug in frontend just for the logged in Administrator users?!

Comment: I've updated my question with more info about settings of system debug plugin

Comment: I followed your suggestions and something weird happen. The query was not shown in the debug area. I tested that in the homepage were all the modules are loaded and the query was not there. I am attaching the results so maybe you can give me some advice.https://www.dropbox.com/s/o3q5rdi82z87h3g/debug.html?dl=0

Comment: How or where did you first found the slow query in your question? Anyway worst query time in this debug is executed from mod_k2_tools, could it be the problem?

Comment: I contacted siteground support and they told me the 500 error of the site was caused because the slow query triggered the auto killing of apache and mysql. 
I have read that k2 tag creates some load, but that query its not the same with the slow query that I got from the support.
As I don't have experience in this issue, could your tell me if the time and load of the queries are normal?!

Comment: On my opinion queries are good, maybe mod_k2_tools and mod_sp_weather are using too much memory. Back on the query, it could be executed from backend or frontend edit, try checking there. Also, if you can, use an editor or a software with "Find in files" function and search for that query inside your website files.

Comment: I am so confused with this, at least here I am getting some pro responses.
About the searching the files content, I have searched all the components/modules/plugins/template .php for "SELECT DISTINCT" but with no result. Maybe this query its generated by merging php variables.

Comment: try searching "g.title AS groupname" or other fields, don't search for mysql statements because they're rewritten by joomla standard code (example: `$query->select("g.title")`)

Comment: Nicola, you gave me a big hint, the "backend" area!!!
Taking as another hint the result of the query => latest k2 items, I went on that menu and the issue was there. 
I will investigate that in details, but its a shame for a backend that loads the latest articles to use this ugly query :(

Comment: Glad you finally solved the issue, or at least found the guilty module!

Answer (score 0):

Use EXPLAIN and check which column have more data and taking time and which field require indexing and then apply it and check speed.

```
EXPLAIN DISTINCT i.*, g.title AS groupname, c.name AS category, v.name AS author, w.name as moderator, u.name AS editor 
FROM p38xt_k2_items as i 
LEFT JOIN p38xt_k2_categories AS c ON c.id = i.catid 
LEFT JOIN p38xt_viewlevels AS g ON g.id = i.access 
LEFT JOIN p38xt_users AS u ON u.id = i.checked_out 
LEFT JOIN p38xt_users AS v ON v.id = i.created_by 
LEFT JOIN p38xt_users AS w ON w.id = i.modified_by 
WHERE i.trash=0 ORDER BY i.id DESC LIMIT 0, 50;
```

Comment: I want to delete the module/plugin/component* that its causing this query!